# Search Vtiger Fields

Tags: vtiger

I am using vtiger 6 and have created a simple products module to log equipment in for service. One of the fields I created is Serial No. I want to be able and search by serial but by default vtiger wont allow and I have to use the advanced search. Is there a way to add a particular field to the basic search function?

Comment: Is this a code-related question? What have you tried?

Comment: yes it is code related. I edited the below but all I get is white screen after.   Edit modules/Products/Products.php 
Find the array definition $list_fields and add the element: 

'Serial No'=>Array('products'=>'serialno'), 

Find the array definition $list_fields_name and add the element: 

'Serial No'=>'serialno',

Comment: It's an old question but still let me contribute. In vtiger 7 the development team has disabled the global search except for specified fields. To change this behaviour go to modules/Vtiger/model/Record.php and look for the "getSearchResults" method.  This is called from the global search for each module separately. So you can add an if statement: if($module=="Equipement") {  $query=" select fields where serial_number like ?  ";   }

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change productname to serialno in modules\Products\Products.php file 
var $def_basicsearch_col = 'productname';